# Trouble running liquibase with different agent

Tags: liquibase

I need to execute the same db-changelog by ant and then by spring. I hope that ant will run the changelog and when spring run, it will not do anything and just stop normally. Ant run the db-changelog successfully and then spring run but it throws an exception, part of the stack trace :

Reason: liquibase.exception.JDBCException: Error executing SQL CREATE TABLE action (action_id int8 NOT NULL, action_name VARCHAR(255), version_no int8, reason_required BOOLEAN, comment_required BOOLEAN, step_id int8, CONSTRAINT action_pkey PRIMARY KEY (action_id)):
          Caused By: Error executing SQL CREATE TABLE action (action_id int8 NOT NULL, action_name VARCHAR(255), version_no int8, reason_required BOOLEAN, comment_required BOOLEAN, step_id int8, CONSTRAINT action_pkey PRIMARY KEY (action_id)):
          Caused By: ERROR: relation "action" already exists; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException....

Any help will much appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

It does sound like it is trying to run the changelog again.  Each changeSet in the changeLog is identified by a combination of the id, author, and the changelog path/filename.  If you run "select * from databasechangelog" you can see the values used.

Your problem may be that you are referencing the changelog file differently from ant and spring therefore generating different filename values.  Usually you will want to include them in the classpath so no matter where and how you run them they have the same path (like "com/example/db.changelog.xml")

Comment: Thanks Nathan, That's really the problem. But I have changed the implementation to run the changelog by spring only to avoid any further headache :D.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem and was able to fix it by altering the filename column of DATABASECHANGELOG to reference the spring resource path. In my case, I was using a ServletContextResource under the WEB-INF directory:

```
update DATABASECHANGELOG set FILENAME = 'WEB-INF/path/to/changelog.xml' where FILENAME = 'changelog.xml'
```